# Block Users from using application at same time

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently working on a relatively complex application developed in Access composed of a front end saved on the users computer and a backend on a central network location. The development has been interesting to say the least, and only now, as we're getting ready to push it out, we've identified some serious bugs that occur with users having concurrent access.

This will take some time to fix, (if of course it's deemed worthy of being fixed at all), and in a rush to make sure the application get's out and used, I need to somehow lock down the application for all other users, when another user opens it up, while still having the separation with several front ends and the single back end. (I.e. User A opens their copy of the front end, now Users B, C and D can't open their copies until User A closes it).

I thought I read somewhere about some way of locking down the entire register in a similar manner to record and page locking, but I can't seem to find anything about it any more.

My current idea is to add a table to the backend that is populated whenever it's used and when someone tries to open the application, and it sees that someone is already on, it closes again. However I'm not sure how it would work if User A's application crashes, or if they go away to make a Cup of Coffee and never return etc.

Anyone else faced a similar issue and if so how would you work around it?

Comment: The idea you have in your last para is the way to go according to me. You can complement that with a hidden form that has a time interval that constantly pings the back end and checks for user activity on the front end. If the user has left the application unattended for more than lets say 1 Hour. It will prompt a pop up message and auto close in lets say 10 Minutes. You can achieve this using time intervals.

Comment: I have found the auto close out can be difficult to use, say the user was editing a record then locked there computer and walked away.  When I have attempted to auto close on that user it just prompts them while their computer is locked asking them if they want to save.  I believe I have tried an auto save and close as well, though I will admit it was quite some time ago.

Comment: Rather than going around, you could tell us the actual "Error/Bug" you are experiencing while in concurrent use. We might be able to get rid of the actual error rather than plastering a dirty job.

Comment: @krishKM The bug isn't to do with access specifically but more so several design decisions made very early on when the scope of the project was very different. We know what's wrong and more or less how to fix it, but it's going to take a very long time and involve re-designing a lot of the application and there are several higher priority tasks to complete first.